# Scanning from terminal

Tags: 11.10, command-line, scanning

I want to be able to scan from the terminal and then send the scanned output to a specific directory. Can this be done from the terminal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`scanimage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/scanimage.1.html) is installed by default.

And here's me using it:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `epson2:libusb:002:003' is a Epson PID 084F flatbed scanner

$ scanimage -d "epson2:libusb:002:003" --format tiff > rawr.tiff
```

Obviously that generates a tiff-formatted file. Lossless but usually quite vast. You can convert this down withou an intermediary file by installing `imagemagick` and then piping the scan output into the `convert` command:

```
$ scanimage -d "epson2:libusb:002:003" --format=tiff | convert tiff:- scan.jpg
```

Comment: Can I save the file as JPEG? `man scanimage` just says I can use `pnm` or `tiff` with `--format`. Neither of these are what I want and both are producing incredibly large files (25 MB!)

Comment: You can convert them with `convert` command in the `imagemagick` package. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Modern scanimage supports png and jpeg natively, no imagemagick required (which is nice)

Answer (score 4):

Tested in 18.04 LTS, works fine.

You may need to set a scan resolution (150/300/600 dpi). To do this use "--resolution" param (this param don't mentioned in [scanimage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/scanimage.1.html) manpage docs). It helps you to reduce the size of produced files.

Example for 600 dpi scan with png output:

`scanimage "epson2:libusb:002:003" --resolution 600 --format=png`

Output file size difference between 300 and 600 dpi is significant if you scan an image (not text).

My values for default A4 image:

- 300 dpi: 2560px * 3150px image, 2-20 Mb *.png file
- 600 dpi: 5120px * 7020px image, 30-65 Mb *.png file

Comment: In order to avoid the error `scanimage: argument without option: 'epson2:libusb:002:003'; try scanimage --help` you need to add `-d ` or `--device-name=` before the device identifier

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple command line tool I wrote for myself to scan documents, uses `scanimage` and `imagemagic` to scan:

**https://github.com/pohape/command-line-scanner**

To get a JPEG file with the scan result:

`./scan.sh ./test.jpg`

To get a PNG file with the scan result:

`./scan.sh ./test.png`

To get a PDF file with the scan result:

`./scan.sh ./test.pdf`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for your answer! It seems that you are the author of the tool in your answer, so can you please [edit] it to disclose your affiliation with the project? See this post from the Help Center: [How to not be a spammer](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog done =)