# Scans, but does not insert

Tags: scanner

In Libre office, click on insert,  media,  scan,  select source.
Scanner window comes up,  click on scan.
Scanner scans, but does not put document into libre office.
Using Linux 17.01 with HP 2130.
Thanks, Fred

Comment: Can you scan with "Simple Scan" ?

Comment: Is it working from CLI? See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106769/scanning-from-terminal) for details.