# How to scan text documents from the command line?

Tags: command-line, scanner, simplescan

I like the way `simple-scan` produces small pdf files for text documents.
Alas, since I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (and still on 18.04), [the keys <kbd>C-1</kbd> (scan 1 page) and <kbd>C-n</kbd> no longer work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1729170), so I have to move the mouse (which is slow), so I am looking for alternatives.

[Compile pdf file from multiple images scanned in by scanimage --batch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136619/31443) and [Scanning from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/106769/80483) offer an excellent approach:

```
$ scanimage --format=tiff | convert tiff:- scan.pdf
```

Alas, the file `scan.pdf` is 10M - for a page which is scanned by `simple-scan` into a **164k PDF file**.

I tried all combinations:

```
for mode in gray line; do 
  for format in png tiff jpeg; do 
    scanimage --mode $mode --resolution 300 --format=$format | convert $format:- $mode-$format.pdf
    ls -h $mode-$format.pdf
  done
done
```

and got

```
5.9M gray-png.pdf
11M  gray-tiff.pdf
1.1M gray-jpeg.pdf
288K line-png.pdf
11M  line-tiff.pdf
1.5M line-jpeg.pdf
```

IOW, the only options producing decent file sizes are `--mode line --format png`.

However, the *quality* of the scan leaves a lot to be desired (e.g., all lines are the same weight - black, there is no gray scale, lots of "dirt"). `gray` produces decent quality, but the file sizes are absurdly huge.

So, how do I scan a text document into PDF the way `simple-scan` does in `text` mode without using my mouse?

PS. I asked this on [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452132/31443) and got no answers.

Comment: When reposting elsewhere on SE, you should delete the original post.

Comment: @muru: never heard this rule. moreover, ISTR that the instruction was to keep questions cross-referenced.

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/295160)

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Just found another Stack Exchange site where .pdf and scanning questions can be posted: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bimage-processing%5D+scan+pdf

Comment: The lack of C-1 is a PAIN. Hope this is going to be fixed?